# Cannot authenticate to IIS using win auth and dotnet 6

Tags: .net, iis, windows-authentication

creating web app using dotnet 6 which should be using win auth.
I have managed to run it locally on IIS Express by setting
this
[(screenshot of launchsettings.json)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaQCj.png)
in the launchSettings.json

I have followed this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/
to enable windows authentication on the server IIS.

Now, when I enter the web url its asking for credentials.
[screenshot of login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfZU1.png)

And here comes the issue.
Its asking for email as username.
But on the server where the IIS is running, my windows account does not have any email set up.
Just username.
I am using the username/password to connect via Remote Desktop.

But here the credentials does not work.

When I enter them, the login screen re-appear again, and again.

Any idea where I have made mistake?

I was trying to go over the setting of my windows account on the server, I have also tried it from different computer and still the same result.

Comment: What happens when you click More Choices? Also is the IIS server joined to the same domain as your client machine?

Comment: No the IIS is no in the same domain. 
More choices is giving me options for Windows hello for my current user. 

The thing is I am on my PC with some windows identity and want to connect to the IIS using different windows identity which I am using on the server machine. 

Its quite possible that I am trying to achieve something which is not possible.

Comment: Then if it's not in the same domain how do you expect it to recognize your Windows Authentication login? This could only work if there is a trust relationship between the two domains (an unusual setup). If the domains don't trust each other then why should the server believe you are who you say you are? It has no knowledge of your domain, cannot contact your Domain Controller, and doesn't trust your DC even if it could contact it.

Comment: If you want to use the identity from the server's domain then you don't need trust, but your client machine will need to have line of sight to the other domain's DC, and will need to be configured to know where that DC is, usually via DNS or reigistry/Group Policy.

Comment: Ok, got it. So without any additional set up on domains level its not possible. 
But, if it would be running inside the same domain, then (theoretically) it should be fine?

Comment: Yes, and you wouldn't need to login as Windows will pass the Kerberos ticket it already has.